# proxy OR rewrite rule to serve static content via cloudfront in proxy server

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

I have apache reverse proxy server(under ELB) in front of apache servers.
I want to serve images and uploads folder via statc.example.com Cname to cloudfront. 
I tried some proxypass and rewrite rule but not worked.

Please help me on this.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it, the below rule worked fine for me.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^static.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(png|js|jpg|gif|ico)$ http://static.example.com/$1.$2 [NE,R=302,L]
```

Hope it help someone.